# How to configure Apache Spark random worker ports for tight firewalls?

Tags: configuration, apache-spark, worker, ports

I am using Apache Spark to run machine learning algorithms and other big data tasks. Previously, I was using spark cluster standalone mode running spark master and worker on the same machine. Now, I added multiple worker machines and due to a tight firewall, I have to edit the random port of worker. Can anyone help how to change random spark ports and tell me exactly what configuration file needs to be edited? I read the spark documentation and it says `spark-defaults.conf` should be configured but I don't know how I can configure this file for particularly changing random ports of spark.

Comment: Wouldn't this question be better suited for serverfault.com as it seems to be a configuration and not a programming issue?

Answer (score 18):

***Update** for Spark 2.x*

---

Some libraries have been rewritten from scratch and many legacy `*.port` properties are now obsolete *(cf. SPARK-10997 / SPARK-20605 / SPARK-12588 / SPARK-17678 / etc)*

For Spark 2.1, for instance, the port ranges on which the driver will listen for executor traffic are

- between `spark.driver.port` and `spark.driver.port`+`spark.port.maxRetries`
- between `spark.driver.blockManager.port` and `spark.driver.blockManager.port`+`spark.port.maxRetries`

And the port range on which the executors will listen for driver traffic and/or other executors traffic is

- between `spark.blockManager.port` and `spark.blockManager.port`+`spark.port.maxRetries`

The "maxRetries" property allows for running several Spark jobs in parallel; if the base port is already used, then the new job will try the next one, etc, unless the whole range is already used.

*Source:*
   https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/configuration.html#networking
   https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.1/security.html under *"Configuring ports"*

Answer (score 11):

check here https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#networking

In the "Networking" section, you can see some of the ports are by default random. You can set them to your choice like below:

```
val conf = new SparkConf() 
    .setMaster(master) 
    .setAppName("namexxx") 
    .set("spark.driver.port", "51810") 
    .set("spark.fileserver.port", "51811") 
    .set("spark.broadcast.port", "51812") 
    .set("spark.replClassServer.port", "51813") 
    .set("spark.blockManager.port", "51814") 
    .set("spark.executor.port", "51815")
```

Comment: Question: Why do you specify executor port - isn't this value for the worker?  (see http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html)

Comment: as I understand, one worker could have multiple executors, and driver process is distributing tasks to executors. Their communication is via tcp protocol and port number. I specify the port so that my firewall will not block the communication, since by default my firewall blocked suspicious ports.

Comment: But the driver doesn't need to open spark.executor.port, it connects to spark.executor.port (on the worker)?

Comment: port is just a tunnel that driver and executor uses to communicate, as I understand, they listen to their open port for incoming message...

Comment: what do you do when you need to run multiple spark jobs?  won't the ports conflict?

Comment: **WARNING:** as of Spark 2.0 most of these properties are deprecated, because the driver/executor communication had been refactored...