# Spark Shell on Yarn getting connection refused error

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, connection-refused

I have Hadoop 2.7.0 and Spark 2.0.0 on Ubuntu 14.04. I have one master node and tw slave nodes. All daemons have started well. When I start spark-shell without Yarn, the following runs fine

```
scala> val inputRDD = sc.textFile("/spark_examples/war_and_peace.txt")
inputRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = /spark_examples/war_and_peace.txt MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> inputRDD.collect
res0: Array[String] = Array(The Project Gutenberg EBook of War and Peace, by Leo Tolstoy, "", This eBook is for the use of anyone anywhere at no cost and with almost, no restrictions whatsoever.  You may copy it, give it away or re-use it, under the terms of the Project Gutenberg License included with this, eBook or online at www.gutenberg.org, "", "", Title: War and Peace, "", Author: Leo Tolstoy, "", Translators: Louise and Aylmer Maude, "", Posting Date: January 10, 2009 [EBook #2600], "", Last Updated: March 15, 2013, "", Language: English, "", Character set encoding: ASCII, "", *** START OF THIS PROJECT GUTENBERG EBOOK WAR AND PEACE ***, "", An Anonymous Volunteer, and David Widger, "", "", "", "", "", WAR AND PEACE, "", By Leo Tolstoy/Tolstoi, "", CONTENTS, "", BOOK ONE: 1805, "",...
scala>
```

But when I start spark-shell with Yarn, it throws the following error

```
scala> val inputRDD = sc.textFile("/spark_examples/war_and_peace.txt")
inputRDD: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = /spark_examples/war_and_peace.txt MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> inputRDD.collect
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 2) / 2]17/04/03 21:31:04 ERROR shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher: Exception while beginning fetch of 1 outstanding blocks 
java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to HadoopSlave2/192.168.78.136:44749
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:228)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:179)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService$$anon$1.createAndStart(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.fetchAllOutstanding(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:140)
    at org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.RetryingBlockFetcher.start(RetryingBlockFetcher.java:120)
    at org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService.fetchBlocks(NettyBlockTransferService.scala:105)
    at org.apache.spark.network.BlockTransferService.fetchBlockSync(BlockTransferService.scala:92)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getRemoteBytes(BlockManager.scala:554)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(TaskResultGetter.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$1.apply(TaskResultGetter.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.logUncaughtExceptions(Utils.scala:1857)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskResultGetter$$anon$2.run(TaskResultGetter.scala:56)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: HadoopSlave2/192.168.78.136:44749
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:224)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:289)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:528)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:111)
    ... 1 more
```

Have I missed anything in the configuration?

Answer (score 1):

Spark uses random ports for internal communications between driver and executors, which might be blocked by your firewall. Try opening ports between your cluster nodes.

You can also use fixed port using this if you are strict about firewall rules even within the cluster,

```
val conf = new SparkConf() 
    .setMaster(master) 
    .setAppName("namexxx") 
    .set("spark.driver.port", "51810") 
    .set("spark.fileserver.port", "51811") 
    .set("spark.broadcast.port", "51812") 
    .set("spark.replClassServer.port", "51813") 
    .set("spark.blockManager.port", "51814") 
    .set("spark.executor.port", "51815")
```

Refer here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/30036642/3080158

Comment: Thanks @RBanerjee. Since I am using spark-shell, I have updated spark-defaults.conf with 
`spark.driver.port 51810 
spark.fileserver.port 51811 
spark.broadcast.port 51812 
spark.replClassServer.port 51813 
spark.blockManager.port 51814 
spark.executor.port 51815`

but still getting errors on the new ports

I have check firewall using `sudo ufw status verbose`
The status shows inactive, so there should not be any firewall.

Any other suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Are nodes connected to each other directly via router, or connected via any company network, or restricted network. In that case you need to check firewall in the network level.

Comment: Hi, These are VMs running on a single physical machine. I am using VMWare Player 12. The VMs are configured to use NAT for networking. I have not specified any rule in VMWare. I can SSH into any of these VMs . from other VMs. Spark's 8080 page shows all nodes running fine.Thanks.