# Ambari Hadoop Spark Cluster Firewall Issues

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop2, ambari

I have just rolled out a Hadoop/Spark cluster in efforts to kick start a data science program at my company. I used Ambari as the manager and installed the Hortonworks distribution (HDFS 2.7.3, Hive 1.2.1, Spark 2.1.1, as well as the other required services. By the way, I am running RHEL 7. I have 2 name nodes, 10 data nodes, 1 hive node and 1 management node (Ambari).

I built a list of firewall ports based on Apache and Ambari documentation and had my infrastructure guys push those rules. I ran into an issue with Spark wanting to pick random ports. When I attempted to run a Spark job (the traditional Pi example), it would fail, as I did not have the whole ephemeral port range open. Since we will probably be running multiple jobs, it makes sense to let Spark handle this and just choose from the ephemeral range of ports (1024 - 65535) rather than specifying a single port. I know I can pick a range, but to make it easy I just asked my guys to open the whole ephemeral range. At first my infrastructure guys balked at that, but when I told them the purpose, they went ahead and did so.

Based on that, I thought I had my issue fixed, but when I attempt to run a job, it still fails with:

```
Log Type: stderr 

Log Upload Time: Thu Oct 12 11:31:01 -0700 2017 

Log Length: 14617 

Showing 4096 bytes of 14617 total. Click here for the full log. 

Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:28:52 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:28:53 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:28:54 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:28:55 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:28:56 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:28:57 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:28:57 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:28:59 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:29:00 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:29:01 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:29:02 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:29:03 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:29:04 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:29:05 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:29:06 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:29:06 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:29:07 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:29:09 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:29:10 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:29:11 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:29:12 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:29:13 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:29:14 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:29:15 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Failed to connect to driver at 10.10.98.191:33937, retrying ...
17/10/12 11:29:15 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception: 
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to connect to driver!
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.waitForSparkDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:607)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runExecutorLauncher(ApplicationMaster.scala:461)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:783)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:67)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1866)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:781)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:804)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
17/10/12 11:29:15 INFO ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 10, (reason: Uncaught exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to connect to driver!)
17/10/12 11:29:15 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
```

At first I thought maybe I had some sort of misconfiguration with Spark and the namenodes/datanodes. However, to test it, I simply stopped firewalld on every node and attempted the job again and it worked just fine.

So, my question - I have the entire 1024 - 65535 port range open - I can see the Spark drivers are trying to connect on those high ports (as show above - 30k - 40k range). However, for some reason when the firewall is on, it fails and when its off it works. I checked the firewall rules and sure enough, the ports are open - and those rules are working as I can access the web services for Ambair, Yarn and HFDS which are specified in the same firewalld xml rules file....

I am new to Hadoop/Spark, so I am wondering is there something I am missing? Is there some lower port under 1024 I need to account for? Here is a list of the ports below 1024 I have open, in addition to the 1024 - 65535 port range:

```
88
111
443
1004
1006
1019
```

It's quite possible I missed a lower number port that I really need and just don't know it. Above that, everything else should be handled by the 1024 - 65535 port range.

Comment: Did you open all ports in *all* directions -- i.e. driver to executors, executors to driver, executors to executors?

Comment: You can force Spark to use a port range that is large enough for practical purposes, but still smaller that "everything"... cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729010/how-to-configure-apache-spark-random-worker-ports-for-tight-firewalls/45772173#45772173

Comment: @Samson Scharfrichter  - Yes, all ports are open on all nodes. Even thought I don't need the exact same ports on all of my boxes, I had them open up the range on all the nodes. As long as firewalld has the range open on all the boxes, that should be all I need, right? I don't think you specify in or out, or do you?

Comment: @Samson Scharfrichter  - Yes, I know I can specify a range, in fact, that is what I had first, but decided to have the whole range opened, just in case, so I could troubleshoot.

Comment: So, something one of my security guys just mentioned is that, even thought i have the ports open, how does the worker node know what port to be listening on.... He's got me convinced that even thought the port range is open, it still needs to be listening on those ports when the spark driver tries to be contacted by the job.... This seems logical, especially since when I turn off firewall services, it works. Am I going down the wrong path here?

Comment: I don't know the specifics of `firewalld` but in **all** firewalls, there are distinct rules for outgoing connections (initiated by a local process) and incoming connections (initiated by a remote process, hence inherently more risky).

Comment: I checked on the incoming/outgoing configuration, and that is not an issue. We don't configure things to that level. We either open the port or we don't open the port. I found another post that seems similar to my issues at: http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/spark-shell-driver-interacting-with-Workers-in-YARN-mode-firewall-blocking-communication-td5237.html . I think what I am facing is that on the data nodes, how does Spark know what port the worker should be listening on? It makes sense that, even though the firewall is open, nothing can connect it nothing is listening....

Comment: So, I decided to start back at square one and assign a specific port via the settings in Spark (in the Ambari interface). Here are those custom settings: spark.blockManager.port = 40000, spark.broadcast.port = 40001, spark.driver.port = 40002, spark.executor.port = 40003, spark.fileserver.port = 40004, spark.replClassServer.port = 40005, spark.port.maxRetries = 5000. I added that last one on as I read that give Spark a range to use. Now things are working. Will this somehow prevent me from running multiple applications at once. That is the feeling I get. What is the purpose of these settings?

Comment: _"how does Spark know what port the worker should be listening on"_ > well, the driver gives some config to Yarn to be delivered to the executors, including its address/port. Then the executor contacts the driver to get its custom JARs, python scripts, files etc and has the opportunity to pass its own address/port...

Comment: _"What is the purpose of these settings?"_ > er... Did you really read the documentation and the post I suggested?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so working with some folks on the Hortonworks community, I was was able to come up with a solution. Basically, you need to have at least one port defined, but you can extend that by specifying the spark.port.MaxRetries = xxxxx. By combining this setting along with the spark.driver.port = xxxxx, you can have a range starting at the spark.driver.port and ending with the spark.port.maxRetries.

If you use Ambari as your manager, the settings are under "Custom spark2-defaults" section (I assume under a fully open-source stack install, this would just be a setting under the normal Spark config):
[image]

I was advised to separate out these ports by 32 count blocks, for example, if you start at 40000 for your driver, you should start the spark.blockManager.port at 40033, etc.. See this post at:

https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/141484/spark-jobs-failing-firewall-issue.html