# How many time the spark UI tries the next port if 4040 not available

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

we are running multiple jobs at the same time using spark (using version 2.1) shell. From last couple of days we are keep on getting the error:

> FAILED: org.spark-project.jetty.server.Server@5552479: java.net.BindException: Address already in use

After reading couple of stack overflow, datastax post I found the spark by default tries the port 4040 for Spark UI for the first time and if it fails it tries the +1 port.

- If lets say 4041 is also not available, how many times Spark tries that?

As per [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729010/how-to-configure-apache-spark-random-worker-ports-for-tight-firewalls) and the [spark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/configuration.html) we can provide `spark.port.maxRetries` configuration which is be default set to 16, but

- is this properties applies for `spark.ui.port` or its only application for `spark.driver.port`?
- How does spark decides which port needs it will use for executor? and lets say I have a job which uses 20 executors so how spark decides what ports to use for those executors? Can we control that?

Answer (score 1):

maxRetries is only for the driver. when sparkContext is initialized, it starts with the one specified in the spark.driver.port and then retires for the maxRetires time by incrementing the port by 1. This port is visible to all the executors allocated by the cluster manager. So if the maxRetires is 16, and if there are 16 SparkContext initiated already, no new sparkContext can be initialized until one of them exits.
Cluster Manager is responsible for acquiring required resource to get the executors and I don't think we have a control over the ports that it acquires. As long the executors are able to communicate back to the driver on the port on which it is initialized, there shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: This port is visible to all the executors allocated by the cluster manager. So if the maxRetires is 16, and if there are 16 SparkContext initiated already, no new sparkContext can be initialized until one of them exits -> For every spark driver/job there is a sparkContext and if a job is having 10 executors will it use next 10 ports?

Comment: spark.driver.port is for the driver only and it gets incremented if the port is already taken by another sparkApplication. Now for the executors, spark.executor.port will be incremented based on the maxRetries. Here are some usefull links about this, https://markobigdata.com/2016/03/13/sparkcontext-allocates-random-ports-how-to-control-the-port-allocation/, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27729010/how-to-configure-apache-spark-random-worker-ports-for-tight-firewalls?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa